# particle never settles in place

Tags: animation, particles, physics

Here is a situation I cannot solve in Blender :confused:

I have a particle emitter, that emits one particle.
there is a cube object that has a force on it with the strength of -50 to suck particle near it
the cube is animated but stops moving at a certain time
the partrricle is getting sucked/pulled by the cube to its origin but it just keeps bouncing eround without settling in place at some point
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6dU-xFeT1A
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Damping/damp/damping factor is the thing you should be looking for in simulation settings in case of issues like this.

[image]

Try increasing it a bit. The value is usually a fraction of the speed or energy that will be reduced during interactions.

Comment: +1 Still it might be possible for the particle to "vibrate" a lot even with damping. To help with that you can additionally increase the _Subframes_ under _Integration_ to a higher value, depending on the _Damp_ value and the _Strength_ of the force field.

Comment: thanks 
cant play with damp as I need responsive fast movement of the particle without drag or damp. 
playing with subframes helps a lot but doesnt stops it fully.

Comment: I would try using a very small value anyway.